# Angularjs ng-repeat not working with md-select and md-option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code where I use ng-repeat with md-select. But it is not working, and drop down is shown blank. If I use ng-repeat with div or html select it works. Please see below,

Angularform:-

```
<div class="col-xs-12 formClass" ng-controller="dropDownController">
  <md-input-container class="formClass">
    <label>Impacts</label>
      <md-select name="impact" id="impact" ng-model="impact">
        <md-option  ng-repeat="impact in impacts.availableImpacts" value="{{impact.id}}">{{ impact.name }}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

js:-

```
app.controller('dropDownController', function ($scope) {          
  $scope.impacts = {
    availableImpacts: [
                        {id: '1', name: 'name1' },
                        { id: '2', name: 'name2' },
                        { id: '3', name: 'name3' }
                      ],
 };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

my angular version is old one for me  md-input-container without this tag work

```
<!--<md-input-container>-->
     <label>impact</label>
       <md-select ng-model="selectedImpact">
          <md-option  ng-repeat="impact in impacts.availableImpacts" value="{{impact.name}}">
        {{impact.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
<!--  </md-input-container>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your md-option tag to look like this:

```
<md-option  ng-repeat="impact in impacts.availableImpacts" ng-value="impact.id">{{ impact.name }}</md-option>
```

Use ng-value instead of just value and remove the {{}}'s.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) for more examples.

Do you the proper angular material scripts included in your project?

Comment: Yes my other angular controllers and directives in same form works well. Only above giving problem. I have tried with above solution but did not work :(

Comment: try this instead of looping in view $scope.availableimpacts=$scope.impacts.availableImpacts[0];  ng-repeat="impact in availableimpacts"   see if it makes any difference

Comment: Have you gotten angular material to work anywhere else?

Comment: no luck yet :( . Everywhere for md-select only I am facing problem. But ng-repeat works fine when I use it with normal 'Select' or 'div'.

Comment: Do any of the other angular material directives work like the check box directive? I'm guessing you don't have angular material properly added. If the other material directives are working, do you get any console errors?

Comment: That also I checked on browser console. I am not finding anything.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select  compare your code to the example with title "Options With Async Search" try to figure out what you are mssing or update your code to plunker where we can take a look and fix & what angularmaterial version are you usin ?

Comment: And angularjs version 1.4.8

Comment: Any other angular supporting libraries I have to use?

Comment: With any other controls ng-repeat will work but not with md-select

Comment: Any solution for this guys?

Answer (score 0):

There seems a problem the way you are binding data,

This works for me,

```
<md-input-container>
     <label>impact</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedImpact">
      <md-option  ng-repeat="impact in impacts.availableImpacts" value="{{impact.name}}">
        {{impact.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

see the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/In7nR77RUHVlslzwoNk5/)

Answer (score 0):

this could be related to this ticket: [Angularjs md-options are showing in Inspect but not on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003456/angularjs-md-options-are-showing-in-inspect-but-not-on-screen)

I am also having issues with md-select not displaying the dropdown even though the 'option' DOM elements are present.

I posted this ticket regarding my particular issue: [md-select doesnt display options and causes freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391097/angular-material-md-select-not-displaying-md-options-and-freezes-page-upon-click)