# Angularjs md-options are showing in Inspect but not on screen

Tags: angularjs

I have angular form and I am using md-select and md-option. But when I click on dropdown, freezes the screen and if I see by inspecting element md-option will be showing.

```
<md-select ng-model="Severities" placeholder="Select a Severity">
    <md-select-label>{{ Severities.name }}</md-select-label> 
    <md-option ng-value="opt.id" ng-repeat="opt in severities.availableOptions">
       {{ opt.name }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>



$scope.severities= { 
    availableOptions: [ 
    {
        id: '1', 
        name: 'name1' 
    }, 
    { 
        id: '2', 
        name: 'name2' 
    }, 
    { 
        id: '3', 
        name: 'name3' 
     } 
     ], };
```

Comment: can you give some controller code?

Comment: $scope.severities= {
    availableOptions: [
                        {id: '1', name: 'name1' },
                        { id: '2', name: 'name2' },
                        { id: '3', name: 'name3' }
                      ],
 };

Comment: When I press F12(Inspect Element) , md-option will have all values. But screen not showing, and freezes the screen

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.severities= { 
     availableOptions: [ 
           {id: '1', name: 'name1' },
           { id: '2', name: 'name2' },
           { id: '3', name: 'name3' }
]};
```

In your model **$scope.severities.name** is nothing and in **md-select-label** you are using this which is wrong.

Try this -

```
<md-select ng-model="Severities" placeholder="Select a Severity">
     <md-option ng-value="opt.id" ng-repeat="opt in severities.availableOptions">
           {{ opt.name }}
      </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Hey I have removed it but still same issue. In chrome I can see some action when I click on dropdown but screen freezes. F12 shows all elements like,

<md-option ng-value="opt.id" ng-repeat="opt in severities.availableOptions" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_6" value="2"><div class="md-text ng-binding">Warning</div></md-option>

Comment: can you make a plunker?

Comment: Hey I found something. That is <md-backdrop class="_md-select-backdrop _md-click-catcher ng-scope" style="position: fixed;"></md-backdrop> is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i prefer using ng-option instead of ng-repeat

```
 <md-select ng-model="Severities" placeholder="Select a Severity" ng-option="opt as opt for opt in severities.availableOptions">

<ng-option ng-selected="true">Select Option</ng-option>

</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while generating values from an Array and to use it in ng-options. According to what I have read, ng-options could be used sometimes via ng-repeat. The alternate which You can use is as follows:

```
<md-select ng-model="Severities" id="Severities"><ng-options ng-repeat="opt in severities.availableOptions" ng-value="{{opt.name}}">{{opt.name}}></ng-options></md-select>
```

The controller code would be as

```
$scope.severities= { 
 availableOptions: [ 
       {id: '1', name: 'name1' },
       { id: '2', name: 'name2' },
       { id: '3', name: 'name3' }
```

]};

but I have used JavaScript to fetch the values selected in ng-options.

```
var severity = document.getElementById("Severities").value;
```

later process the severity value present in variable severity.

Comment: If using angularJS no need to use javascript to get the value of dropdown ng-model is used for the same purpose

Comment: Yes, but I was not able to get the value from ng-model in controller..if I use $scope.modelName and alert it, the alert was saying undefined..so I used javascript..

Comment: In your code i think you have missed {{ }} these brackets in ng-value attribute..if you use it i think the drop down will show up..

Comment: Dont do this ask a separate question for that. And you have to have a dot in $scope models. Dont define scope like $scope.xyz do like this $scope.x.yz