# Angular Material md-select not displaying md-options and freezes page upon click

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I just updated the version of Angular Material I am using to 1.0.6

Now when I use md-select + md-option, although all the correct options and corresponding md-option DOM elements display in the inspector, the drop down list does not display upon click, and instead the page (Chrome browser) freezes completely. No console error is thrown.

Here is my code:

```
md-select(
  aria-label='select number of seats'
  ng-show="bookable.seatsperbooking>1"
  ng-model="appt.seats")

  md-option(
    ng-repeat='num in getnumber(seatsallowed) track by $index'
    value='{{num}}') {{ num }}
```

and here is a screenshot of the inspector, which shows the correct number of option DOM elements:
[screenshot of options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeGb7.png)

Comment: What version of Material were you using when this worked? Also, can you see if the issue still persists if you upgrade to 1.1.0-rc2?

Comment: @TopherFangio I did find out it was a version compatibility issue. I was trying to use angular 1.3.20 with angular-material 1.0.7. Once I upgraded to angular 1.4.10 everything worked fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working; you should post an answer on this question so that future users can see how you solved it without having to read all of the comments :-)

Answer (score 2):

This was happening because the Angular + Angular Material versions I was using were incompatible. Angular Material 1.0.7 seems to require at least Angular 1.4 (Angular Material 1.0.7 was not working with Angular 1.3.20)

Answer (score 2):

Having same problem. 
After updating AngularJS to newer version 1.5.5 (w/ Angular Material 1.0.7) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. I have Angular Material 1.1.0.

Updated Angular from 1.3.15 to 1.5.8. Fixed.